# Need a Category List for the category slug

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, categories

I am not sure I explained this right but for my main category slug I would like a list of all my categories. So when someone goes to https://mojiedit.com/category/ for example, it will present a category list. Any thoughts? I can't seem to find a plugin that does this and just receive a 404 error.